# glxgears/glxinfo/glxheads all fail via ssh -X

Tags: nvidia, opengl

So, I have been googling like a mad man but finally have to resort to ask the better knowing. This problem is discussed a lot but nothing have helped me.

Setup: We have a Ubuntu setup:

- Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
- Release:  16.04
- Codename: xenial
- Graphics card: Quadro K5200

From the server room console we installed the nvidia drivers via:

```
sudo -E  add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo -E  apt-get update
sudo -E  apt-get install nvidia-390
sudo nvidia-xconf
```

Edited the *xorg.conf* by adding:

```
Section "ServerFlags"  
    Option "AllowIndirectGLX" "on"  
    Option "IndirectGLX" "on"  
EndSection

Section "Device"
     Identifier     "Device0"
      Driver         "nvidia"
      VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
      BoardName      "Quadro K5200"
      Option    "AllowUnofficialGLXProtocol" "true" (added)
EndSection
```

I also added *+iglx* to */usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf*:

```
[SeatDefaults]

#Dump core

xserver-command=X -core +iglx
```

Rebooted the server with the DVI cable attached to the screen so that the drivers would load and that looks good:

With `sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK110GL [Quadro K5200]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:186 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Installed *mesa-utils*.

From the server room console I can run `glxgears`, `glxinfo` and `glxheads` without problem.

When connecting via `ssh -X` from my Ubuntu machine I get the classical error:

```
$ glxgears 
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  24
  Current serial number in output stream:  25
```

(also after installing the drivers thinlinc does not work anymore).

The libraries and symlinks seem OK?

```
sudo find /usr -iname "*libGL.so*" -exec ls -l -- {} + 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 maj 16 22:00 /usr/lib32/nvidia-390/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 maj 16 22:00 /usr/lib32/nvidia-390/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.390.59    
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  523944 maj 10 06:49 /usr/lib32/nvidia-390/libGL.so.1.7.0    
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1129724 maj 10 06:51 /usr/lib32/nvidia-390/libGL.so.390.59    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 maj 16 22:00 /usr/lib/nvidia-390/libGL.so -> libGL.so.1    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 maj 16 22:00 /usr/lib/nvidia-390/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.390.59    
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  665720 maj 10 06:52 /usr/lib/nvidia-390/libGL.so.1.7.0    
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1268112 maj 10 06:53 /usr/lib/nvidia-390/libGL.so.390.59    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 maj 30 14:44 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2.0    
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  467520 jan 29 21:08 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2.0
```

I know that using `ssh -X` does not use the server card to render the graphics (the next step would be to install virtualGL) but I just want users to be able to at least open programs that use openGL (I'm not a computer scientist so not sure this is correct, what I mean is programs that for example display 3D objects).

On our old setup using RedHat I managed this. Users could open a 3D program via

`ssh -X` = Laggy but works since it renders locally (my computer)

`thinlinc` = less laggy since rendering is done at the server via CPU

`vglconnect` = no lag since the local server GPU does the rendering

But here I cannot get past step 1.

I cannot see if the correct libraries are used since even this gives the same error:

```
LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears

X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)    
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)    
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)    
  Value in failed request:  0x0    
  Serial number of failed request:  24    
  Current serial number in output stream:  25
```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be wrong? Last time I installed the drivers via the nvidia .run file but most people seem to recommend using apt-get since installing via .run is sensitive to  kernel updates(?).

Edit:
On our other very similar server without a graphics card I get the same error as I get on this server prior to installing the nvidia drivers:

```
$ glxgears 
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

But `glxinfo` does give output.

Edit2: glxinfo and glxgears works when using ssh -X from my Windows laptop via mobaXterm. Although it says:

```
GL_VERSION 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 10.5.4)
GL_VENDOR Mesa Project
GL_RENDERER Software Rasterizer
```